# gulp-plumber module cannot be found?

Tags: npm, package, gulp, gulp-plugin

I'm fairly new to Gulp and I can't overcome one issue.

I need to install my dependencies globally (not locally), so I've done npm -g install & also tried to install them all separately with -g flag.

Anyway, SASS works, Coffee works, everything works, but when I run "gulp" i get:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-plumber'
```

Checking if it's installed:

```
npm list -g gulp-plumber

/usr/local/lib
└── gulp-plumber@1.0.1
```

Looks a-okay.

Checking SASS the same way:

```
npm list -g gulp-sass
/usr/local/lib
└── gulp-sass@2.1.0
```

If they're both installed why my gulp "can't see" plumber alone? How do I fix that?

Comment: You can try `npm cache clean` delete `node_modules` and reinstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below command it should work.

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```